# Refactoring A && B && B > A

Tags: javascript, logic

There is a way to refactor this logic expression?

```
A && B && B > A
```

Just learning and I would like to know another way of writing the same expression
Thank you

Comment: What do you think this expression represents?  What are A and B?

Comment: Scott Hunter, are booleans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the expressions and put them in variables with readable names.

Due to the lack of information about what A and B are, I assume the first half of the expression makes sure both values are truthy and then you compare them:

```
const bothTruthy= A && B;
const BLargerThanA = B > A;

const yourExpression = bothTruthy && BLargerThanA;
```

Comment: I tested this solution in tests from my answer, it works but [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) doesn't work in this solution

Comment: So it would be the same expression, but in more readable way

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Okay, the below solution doesn't work for all cases.

I think you don't need to refactor your expression logic if you want `A` and `B` to be interpreted as true. During the processing of logical expressions, **the engine independently optimizes them and performs a [lazy way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)**, for example: if in the expression `A && (B || C)` the value `A` is interpreted as `false`, then the processing of the expression will end immediately and the value `A` will be returned (`false` or an equivalent value), but if the value of `A` is interpreted as`true`, then processing of the condition will continue. Further, if `B` is interpreted as `true`, then due to *logical addition(OR)*, processing will end with a value equivalent to `true`, and if `B` is interpreted as `false`, then processing will continue...

---

Try this - `A && (B > A)`

```js
const cases = [
  [true, false],
  [false, true],
  [false, false],
  [true, true],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 1],
  [1, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [undefined, 1],
  [1, undefined],
  [undefined, 0],
  [0, undefined],
  [null, undefined],
  [undefined, null],
  [1, NaN],
  [NaN, 1],
  [0, NaN],
  [NaN, 0],
  [{}, 0],
  [1, {}],
  [{}, []],
  [[], {}],
  ['2', 1],
  [1, '2'],
  [true, 1],
  [1, true],
  [true, '1'],
  ['1', true],
  [0, -1],
  [-1, 0],
  [1, -1],
  [-1, 1],
  [false, -1],
  [-1, false]
];

const fails = [];

cases.forEach((c) => {
  const [A, B] = c;
  const r1 = A && B && (B > A);
  const r2 = A && (B > A); // <-- simplified condition
  const r = !!r1 === !!r2;
  if (!r) fails.push({c: c, r1, r2});
});

if (fails.length > 0) {
  console.log('Not all cases passed!');
  console.log(fails);
} else {
  console.log('All cases passed!');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The simplified expression fails when A is negative and B is 0 or null, but maybe the original expression is not correct when A or B is 0 (I don't know if the request was to ignore the number 0, or only for nulls)

Comment: @ManuelRomeiro okay i added additional tests. I'll think about how I can fix it

Comment: It's not the same expression A && (B > A)

Comment: @Bernardao I know I have already updated the answer, read what I added